# php mysql, login script. My error message doesn't show

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make an php, mysql login script. when I'm typing wrong username or password or login id it don't show my error message. Why?

```
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
$p_nickname = $_POST['p_nickname'];
$p_password = $_POST['p_password'];
if(!empty($c_id)&&!empty($p_nickname)&&!empty($p_password)){
    $query = "SELECT c_id, p_nickname, p_password FROM people_inside_company INNER JOIN company ON pic_c_id = c_id INNER JOIN people ON pic_code_number = p_code_number WHERE c_id = '$c_id' AND p_nickname = '$p_nickname' AND p_password = '$p_password'";
    #t
    if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die(mysqli_error($con))){
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $in_cid = $row['c_id'];
            $in_pnickname = $row['p_nickname'];
            $in_ppassword = $row['p_password'];
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($count == 1){
                echo "you're in";
                # i get this when i type the right c_id, p_nickname and p_passowrd
                #more code
            }
            else{
                echo "wrong username, password or id";
                # i don't get this when im typing the wrong c_id, p_nickname or p_password, why?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are always getting printed `You're in` ?

Comment: if i write the right nickname and password and c_id yes, if i typ wrong it doesn't show me anything,

Comment: Use parameterized queries and hash your user's passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code :

```
  $con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
$p_nickname = $_POST['p_nickname'];
$p_password = $_POST['p_password'];
if(!empty($c_id)&&!empty($p_nickname)&&!empty($p_password)){
    $query = "SELECT c_id, p_nickname, p_password FROM people_inside_company INNER JOIN company ON pic_c_id = c_id INNER JOIN people ON pic_code_number = p_code_number WHERE c_id = '$c_id' AND p_nickname = '$p_nickname' AND p_password = '$p_password'";
    #t
    if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die(mysqli_error($con))){

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $in_cid = $row['c_id'];
            $in_pnickname = $row['p_nickname'];
            $in_ppassword = $row['p_password'];
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($count == 1){
                echo "you're in";
                # i get this when i type the right c_id, p_nickname and p_passowrd
                #more code
            }

        }
        else
        {
                echo "wrong username, password or id";
                # i don't get this when im typing the wrong c_id, p_nickname or p_password, why?
            }

    }
}
```

your "else" block was unreachable (logically)

Comment: @Olle Norström . use the updated code .. and do vote my answer . please use the latest updated code

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way

```
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     die('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
  $c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
  $p_nickname = $_POST['p_nickname'];
  $p_password = $_POST['p_password'];

 if (!empty($c_id) && !empty($p_nickname) && !empty($p_password)) {

$query = "SELECT c_id, p_nickname, p_password FROM people_inside_company INNER JOIN company ON pic_c_id = c_id INNER JOIN people ON pic_code_number = p_code_number WHERE c_id = '$c_id' AND p_nickname = '$p_nickname' AND p_password = '$p_password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$in_cid = $row['c_id'];
$in_pnickname = $row['p_nickname'];
$in_ppassword = $row['p_password'];

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "you're in";
} else {
    echo "wrong username, password or id";
}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't place `mysqli_query` inside the `if` condition because if any of the inputs are wrong, the result of the `if` condition will be false, so it won't really show anything.

Try doing this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
$p_nickname = $_POST['p_nickname'];
$p_password = $_POST['p_password'];
if(!empty($c_id)&&!empty($p_nickname)&&!empty($p_password)){
    $query = "SELECT c_id, p_nickname, p_password FROM people_inside_company INNER JOIN company ON pic_c_id = c_id INNER JOIN people ON pic_code_number = p_code_number WHERE c_id = '$c_id' AND p_nickname = '$p_nickname' AND p_password = '$p_password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $in_cid = $row['c_id'];
            $in_pnickname = $row['p_nickname'];
            $in_ppassword = $row['p_password'];
        }

        echo "you're in";
    }
    else{
        echo "wrong username, password or id";
    }
}
```

Also, if you're doing any database transactions with user input, you should use [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) because with this code, you have caused an [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Answer (score 0):

When you record is empty it will not go inside the loop,so you were not getting error message.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
$p_nickname = $_POST['p_nickname'];
$p_password = $_POST['p_password'];

if(!empty($c_id)&&!empty($p_nickname)&&!empty($p_password)){
   $query = "SELECT c_id, p_nickname, p_password FROM people_inside_company   INNER JOIN company ON pic_c_id = c_id INNER JOIN people ON pic_code_number = p_code_number WHERE c_id = '$c_id' AND p_nickname = '$p_nickname' AND p_password = '$p_password'";

    if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die(mysqli_error($con))){
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

       if($count == 1){
        $in_cid = $row['c_id'];
        $in_pnickname = $row['p_nickname'];
        $in_ppassword = $row['p_password'];
            echo "you're in";
            # i get this when i type the right c_id, p_nickname and p_passowrd
            #more code
       }
       else{
        echo "wrong username, password or id";
        # i don't get this when im typing the wrong c_id, p_nickname or p_password, why?
      }
   }
}
```